# Home Router, Fairly Share Internet Connection

Tags: router, internet, modem

I have just moved into a new house with some friends at my University! Exciting times, but what we didn't realise is that we are all heavy internet users, currently causing problems in the house.

The problem appears to be that if someone starts say streaming a video or downloading software, or running steam updates it appears the whole network grinds to a halt and they get priority on the network. (Almost as if QOS has gone crazy). This means that everyone else in the house's internet is unusable and in most cases the culprit doesn't even realise they are doing it.

I am confident it is not a bandwidth problem as the 'culprit' can get download speeds up to and beyond 5Mbps.

We have a TG585v7 (O2 Wireless II Box) in the house and I have trawled through the settings to find anything on network priority etc but there is none.

Does anyone know what is causing this problem and what steps we could take to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest method is installing "[cFosSpeed](http://www.cfos.de/en/cfosspeed/cfosspeed.htm)" on every client, and that will manage traffic. Even report in real time to others, so it'll be able to manage the whole house instantly. (Like one person is using the connection for Youtube and MSN. If the other clients will demand speed, it'll prioritize the packets in a correct order. **You can also set up a custom priority on every PC. Just try the trial version.**)

(I asked customer support a while ago, and they told me it's fine if I use only one license with multiple PCs... but if I can, support them with more license.)

Anyway, cFos is *one* option.
Other options are having a [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) or similar router firmware, which got a QoS and other prioritization software which let's you share your connection 'equally'.

Comment: Any recommendations for linux and/or Mac software that does the same thing? That's what I have.

Comment: @Yitzchak - You should go with the custom router firmware. There are complex firewalls, etc capable of doing so, but you would need a complete PC for that (or a MikroTik router board?). Anyway, that costs money. (Elecricity, or hardware. Or both.)

Answer (score 0):

You'll most likely find that it's the ACK packets that are not getting through, and the problem for everyone else will be the latency issues rather than the bandwidth.

If you've got an old computer lying around you can use [pfSense](http://pfsense.com/) or [monowall](http://m0n0.ch/wall/) on it and that will give you quite fine grained control (such as by host, by protocol etc).